# Не работает Bluetooth в ArchLinux KDE

Tags: linux, bluetooth, archlinux, kde

Не работает Bluetooth в ArchLinux KDE.
Не всегда видит устройства и не подключается к ним.
Пробовал гуглить но не один гайд не помог.

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
```

Результат:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-06-22 16:01:22 MSK; 21min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 4102 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38396)
     Memory: 1.3M
        CPU: 56ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─4102 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

июн 22 16:19:11 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DP>
июн 22 16:19:11 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.74 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DP>
июн 22 16:19:12 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.228 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS>
июн 22 16:19:12 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.228 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS>
июн 22 16:19:12 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.228 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS>
июн 22 16:19:12 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.228 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS>
июн 22 16:19:12 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.228 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS>
июн 22 16:19:12 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.228 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS>
июн 22 16:19:12 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.228 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS>
июн 22 16:19:12 Gra4evArchLinux bluetoothd[4102]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.228 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPS>
```

---

```
dmesg | grep Bluetooth
```

Результат:

```
[    5.632230] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.632248] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.632251] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.632253] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.632256] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.778574] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
[    5.778622] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x24800
[    5.778624] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 50-12.22
[    5.778625] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[    7.164252] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.164255] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.164258] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.232960] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.232966] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.232969] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Пробовал через Bluetooth KDE и Blueman устройства то видит, то нет. Но никогда не подключается.

Под виндой все нормально работает. В Fedora 35 работал, в Fedora 36 перестал, в Arch не завелся изначально.

Answer (score 1):

можешь попробовать собрать из аура arch-linux-tweak-tool, я тоже не мог стартануть сервис когда наушники купил, а он справился, в последних версиях Эрик добавил разные сервисы и гуи к ним

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]